# Sharepoint: Javascript - Getting List Data (including LOOKUP columns)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have a list with a LOOKUP column to another list. The lookup column is called "Employee" and I want to GET the values from the "Employment Type" field. However I keep on getting a request error. What is wrong with my statement below. Before, I was only looking for choice and $ columns.Everything worked fine until I inserted the `Employee/Employment_Type&$expand=Employee` part

```js
    xhr.open('GET', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'' + listName + 
       '\')/items?  $Funding$Funding_Type$Vacant&Direct&Employee/Employment_Type$select=ID,Employee/Employment_Type&$expand=Employee&$top=1000');
```

also, is my `Employment_Type = results[i].Employee/Employment_Type` syntax correct below?

Note: I am only including a small part of the overall script

```js
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
        if (results[i].Direct == "DCSP" & results[i].Funding == "A-Base") {  
            dcsp_abaseSal += results[i].SalEnv3
            Employment_Type = results[i].Employee/Employment_Type
            TypeSal = results[i].SalEnv3
            dcsp_vacant_days += results[i].Vacant_Days
            dcsp_variance = dcsp_abase_cap - dcsp_abaseSal
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's the usage of '$Funding$Funding_Type$Vacant&Direct&Employee/Employment_Type'?

Comment: Hi, I am newish to Javascript. However, if I don't include that section of code, no values are returned. They are all columns that I utilize somewhere else in my script. Any suggestions? The Employee/Employment Type is the lookup column(s) that I am trying to add. Sorry for the late reply, I missed the comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rest api get look up column:

```
/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('test3')/items(1)?$select=Title,columnTitle/Title&$expand=columnTitle
```

You could add columns which you want to get  after $select like columnTitle/sourceColumnTitle

Comment: Hi, I tried the following but I get a request failed error. Where did I go wrong? Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: xhr.open('GET', _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle(\'' + listName + '\')/items?ID$select=ID,Employee/Employment_Type&$expand=Employment_Type$top=1000');

Comment: note: if I exclude the "Employee/Employment_Type&$expand=Employment_Type", my script works fine for NON lookup fields/columns

Comment: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listName + "')/items?$select=ID,Employee/Employment_Type&$expand=Employment_Type$top=1000"